# Flow chart using R

Tags: r, flowchart

I've been struggling the whole day with creating a flow chart to represent some patients we included in a study.

I already have a rough version ready in a Power Point presentation, depicting what kind of arrangement I'm looking for.

[image: Structure I'm trying to recreate]

Now, I've got all my boxes ready, but what I need is the same alignment and connection to the arrows as in the picture attached. I have tried to somewhat copy and paste the guide on this page https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Grid-based_flowcharts.html, but now I'm stuck. Since I have little expertise using R and only work with it occasionally, there might be something easy you might see, that I don't.

Here's my code:

```
  install.packages("Gmisc")
library(Gmisc, quietly = TRUE)
library(glue)
library(htmlTable)
library(grid)
library(magrittr)

org_cohort <- boxGrob(glue("Patients with pancreatic cancer admitted to the University Clinic of Essen",
                           "from 01/2002 to 08/2020",
                           "n = {pop}",
                           pop = txtInt(909),
                           .sep = "\n"))
included <- boxGrob(glue("Patients with genetic sequencing and survival data",
                         "n = {incl}",
                         incl = txtInt(412),
                         .sep = "\n"))
grp_a <- boxGrob(glue("Patients treated with FOLFIRINOX or Gemcitabine / nab-Paclitaxel",
                      "n = {recr}",
                      recr = txtInt(179),
                      .sep = "\n"))

grp_b <- boxGrob(glue("Patients with genetic sequencing data via MAPK-TRON panel",
                      "n = {recr}",
                      recr = txtInt(185),
                      .sep = "\n"))

excluded_1 <- boxGrob(glue("Excluded (n = {tot}):",
                         " - No survival data: {NoSurv}",
                         " - No MAPK-Tron panel and early available abdominal CT-scan: {NoMAPKCT}",
                         tot = 506,
                         NoSurv = 300,
                         NoMAPKCT = 206,
                         .sep = "\n"),
                    just = "left")

excluded_2 <- boxGrob(glue("Excluded (n = {NoFGP}):",
                           " - No FOLFIRINOX or Gemcitabine / nab-Paclitaxel as 1st line: {NoFGP}",
                           NoFGP = 233,
                           .sep = "\n"),
                      just = "left")

excluded_3 <- boxGrob(glue("Excluded (n = {NoMAPK}):",
                           " - No sequencing data available: {NoMAPK}",
                           NoMAPK = 227,
                           .sep = "\n"),
                      just = "left")

grid.newpage()
vert <- spreadVertical(org_cohort = org_cohort,
                       included = included,
                       grps = grp_a)
grps <- alignVertical(reference = vert$grp_a,
                      grp_a, grp_b) %>%
  spreadHorizontal()
vert$grps <- NULL

excluded_1 <- moveBox(excluded_1,
                    x = .8,
                    y = coords(vert$included)$top + distance(vert$included, vert$org_cohort, half = TRUE, center = FALSE))

excluded_2 <- moveBox(excluded_2,
                      x = .8,
                      y = coords(vert$grp_a)$top + distance(vert$included, vert$grp_a, half = TRUE, center = FALSE))

excluded_3 <- moveBox(excluded_3,
                      x = .8,
                      y = coords(vert$grp_b)$bottom + distance(vert$included, vert$grp_b, half = TRUE, center = FALSE))

## already facing problems here: R gives me the following error message: Error in coords(vert$grp_a/b) : 
  #Assertion on 'box' failed: Must inherit from class 'box', but has class 'NULL'..

for (i in 1:(length(vert) - 1)) {
  connectGrob(vert[[i]], vert[[i + 1]], type = "vert") %>%
    print
}
connectGrob(vert$included, grps[[1]], type = "N")
connectGrob(vert$included, grps[[2]], type = "N")

connectGrob(vert$included, excluded_1, type = "L")
connectGrob(vert$grp_a, excluded_2, type = "L")



# Print boxes
vert
grps
excluded_1
excluded_2
excluded_3
```

I'll be honest: I don't really get the code after the "grid.newpage()" thing. Therefore I'm constantly trying something to understand what the components of the code actually do, but every time I think I understood how it works, another setback is waiting for me around the corner.
R basically gives me a plot with arrows and boxes all over the place, but not the way I want them to look like. Then sometimes my boxes are even too large or something? Especially the boxes of the two subgroups at the end of the chart are cut-off oftentimes...

Do you have an idea how to "force" R replicating that kind of chart (see picture) for me?

Your help is extremely appreciated and would bring me a step closer to finally finish my thesis...!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I might also consider using the `DiagrammeR` package for something like this: https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-build-a-simple-flowchart-with-r-diagrammer-package/

Comment: @Ben Thank you, this looks definitely easier... I'll try this out later!

Comment: Okay so DiagrammeR does not seem to have a function to connect a box vertically and horizontally at the same time with two other boxes... Maybe I'm missing something, but I did not find any clue on how to do it with this package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something to get your started with `DiagrammeR`.

- Use `splines = ortho` to get 90 degree angles and straight lines.
- Add line breaks with `<br/>` in the labels of nodes.
- Use blank nodes to get branches for exclusion boxes. Then use `rank`
  to get the hidden blank nodes to line up with exclusion boxes.

Hope this is helpful.

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz(
     "digraph my_flowchart { 
      graph[splines = ortho]
      node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = box, width = 4, height = 1]
      
        node1[label = <Pancreatic cancer patients treated at our center<br/>diagnosed 2002-2020<br/>(n = 909)>]
        node2[label = <Patients with MAPK-TRON panel and/or<br/>early available abdominal CT scan (n = 412)>]
        
        blank1[label = '', width = 0.01, height = 0.01]
        excluded1[label = <Exclusion of patients without<br/>(1) MARK-TRON panel and early available abdominal CT scan, and<br/>(2) survival data<br/>(n = 506)>]
        
        node1 -> blank1[dir = none];
        blank1 -> excluded1[minlen = 2];
        blank1 -> node2;
        { rank = same; blank1 excluded1 }
        
        node3[label = <FOLFIRINOX or Gemcitabine/nab-Paclitaxel as first CTx<br/>(n = 179)>]
        node4[label = <Patients with MAPK-TRON panel regardless of CT scans<br/>(n = 185)>]
        
        blank2[label = '', width = 0.01, height = 0.01]
        excluded2[label = <Exclusion of patients that did not receive<br/>FOLFIRINOX or Gemcitabine/nab Paclitaxel as first CTx<br/>(n = 233)>]
        
        blank3[label = '', width = 0.01, height = 0.01]
        excluded3[label = <Exclusion of patients without MAPK-TRON panel<br/>(n = 227)>]
        
        node2 -> blank2[dir = none];
        node2 -> blank3[dir = none];
        
        blank2 -> excluded2[minlen = 2];
        blank3 -> excluded3[minlen = 2];
        
        blank2 -> node3;
        blank3 -> node4;
        
        { rank = same; blank2 excluded2 blank3 excluded3 }
     }"
)
```

**Diagram**

[image: diagrammer image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This is indeed very helpful and i will use this as a template to tweak the diagram a little more!